# What does Believers Eastern Church teach on the mode and subjects of baptism?

Tags: baptism, christianity-in-india

Believers Eastern Church, the denomination from Kerala, India, is an interesting mix of Orthodox, Evangelical, and other traditions. One thing I haven't found out yet is what they teach on baptism. Is it only for believers, or are infants baptized? And is immersion the only mode or are pouring and sprinkling accceptable?

Answer (score 2):

After searching through numerous web sites, including the official Believers Eastern Church, I have been unable to find anything specifically about believers’ baptism, infant baptism, full water immersion or sprinkling.  The following extracts shed some light (but not much) on their beliefs:

> The faith of Believers Eastern Church is rooted in the Apostle's doctrines and Holy Tradition of the “one, holy, catholic and apostolic Church.” We believe the Bible to be the inspired and infallible Word of God, given to us by the Holy Church, “the pillar and ground of the truth” (1 Timothy 3:15). We believe that the Holy Church has continued unbroken through the teachings of the the Apostles’ doctrines, the Holy Tradition and the teachings of the Orthodox Fathers, as preserved in the Nicene and Apostle's Creeds and affirmed by the first seven Ecumenical Church Councils: The first council of Nicaea, first council of Constantinople, council of Ephesus, council of Chalcedon, second council of Constantinople, third council of Constantinople, and the second council of Nicaea .

> Adhering to the biblical faith of the ancient Church is Orthodoxy; therefore, we hold fast to that which has been the common, Scripturally-based faith from the beginning. However, each generation needs to practice and teach this Orthodox faith without compromise in a way that is understood and applicable by its culture and era.

> ***From the Nicene Creed: We acknowledge one baptism for the remission of sins; and we look for the resurrection of the dead and the life of the world to come.***
> Source: https://www.bec.org/faith-and-beliefs/

> Believers Eastern Church (previously Believers Church) is an Oriental Protestant Church of Indian origin with congregations and parishes worldwide. It is also a branch of the ministry Gospel for Asia. The church now follows an episcopal governance. Source:  https://www.bec.org/

Believers Eastern Church has its roots in Pentecostalism.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believers_Eastern_Church#History

***Believers Church administers the sacraments of Baptism and Holy Communion.***   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believers_Eastern_Church#Faith_and_practice

And that's all I could find, apart from a mention that the founder, K. P. Yohannan, had links to a Baptist seminary.  More about him here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._P._Yohannan

EDIT: I asked a question about the Believers Eastern Church in Asia and their claim to be an "Ancient-Future Church".  Two answers provide additional information and links but no mention of baptism.  You may find it useful: [What does it mean that the Believers Eastern Church (in Asia) is an "Ancient-Future Church"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77811/what-does-it-mean-that-the-believers-eastern-church-in-asia-is-an-ancient-fut)